# bat to generate m3u files in multiple folders excluding specific extension

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have the following bat file which will look at each subfolder in my directory and create an m3u file which lists the contents of that subfolder:

```
@echo off

for /d %%A in (*) do @if exist "%%~A\*" (
    for %%B in ("%%~A\*") do @echo %%~nxB
) > "%%~A\%%~nxA.m3u"
```

example:
My directory called Names has subfolders Paul, Tom, Susan.
Paul has files a.txt, b.txt
Tom has files c.txt, d.txt
Susan has files e.txt, f.txt

The bat file, in the Names directory runs. It will create:

- a Paul.m3u file inside the Paul subfolder
- a Tom.m3u file inside the Tom subfolder
- a Susan.m3u file inside the Susan subfolder

Each of the m3u files will list that subfolder's files, one file per line.

The problem I am having is that the m3u file is ALSO listing the m3u files itself. I don't want that.

Current output:

```
a.txt
b.txt
Paul.m3u
```

Wanted output:

```
a.txt
b.txt
```

I recognize that the issue lies in my loop which isn't excluding the .m3u file extension but I'm not sure how to accomplish that. Any pointers?

Comment: `for %%B in ("%%~A\*.txt") do …`?

Comment: The simple solution is to specify the type of files to find instead of all files like `for %%B in ("%%A\*.txt" "%%A\*.lst") do` to process only the files with file extension `.txt` or `.lst` in the currently to process directory. `%%~A` is not really necessary as the outer `for` assigns each found name of a non-hidden directory always without surrounding `"` to the loop variable `A`. It is of course also possible to use just `*` and use a case-insensitive string comparison condition like `for %%B in ("%%A\*") do if /I not "%%~xB" == ".m3u" echo %%~nxB`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for %%B in ("%%~A\*") do if "%%~nxB" neq "%%~nxA.m3u" @echo %%~nxB
```

[untested]

should do what you appear to want, excluding the name.ext part of the .mp3 file being created.

Note that the `@`s are not required once an `@echo off` has been executed.